# Bullhorn API+WordPress integration+customization

Tags: wordpress, api

I actually want to be able to capture contacts, leads, clients, not just candidates and resumes. Is this possible with Bullhorn?  Can I create a custom form that captures info that I want or is there just one way that they allow?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Yes look at https://matadorjobs.com it does most of what you need and you can hook into the API to do the rest

look for the referral to leads add-on